# Import data row to datatable using dataview

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable

I want to insert a row from data view to data table. I am using the following code to insert dataview to datatable but it returns an error.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.DataRowView' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.
```

This is my partial code:

```
string empid= lbxempname.Items[i].Text.Substring(0,8);
DataView dv = new DataView();
dv = DS.DefaultView;
dv.RowFilter = "fldempid='" + empid + "'";
foreach (DataRow Dr in dv) {
  DST.ImportRow(Dr);
}
```

Comment: did u try this `MyDataTable.Rows.Add(MyDataView.Item(0).DataRow.ItemArray)`

Answer (score 2):

A `DataView` contains `DataRowViews` and this has a property [`Row`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview.row.aspx) which references the `DataRow`.

```
foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
{
    DataRow dr = drv.Row;
}
```

But you cannot import that row into a DataTable if it belongs to another DataTable. I would use `LINQ-To-DataSet` to filter your rows and [`CopyToDataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb396189.aspx) to create a new `DataTable` from it.

For example:

```
DataTable tblFiltered = DS.AsEnumerable()
                          .Where(r => r.Field<string>("fldempid") == empid)
                          .CopyToDataTable();
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help?

```
foreach (DataRow row in dv)
{
    dt.LoadDataRow(row.ItemArray);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DST = dv.ToTable();
```

This line of code goes after you set filter for DataView.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataView dview = new DataView();
DataTable dtable = new DataTable();
dtable = dview.Table.Clone();
foreach(DataRowView drowview in dview)
dtable.ImportRow(drowview.Row);
```